# What are the available NSSortDescriptors for PHFetchOptions?

Tags: ios, swift, nssortdescriptor, photokit, phfetchoptions

I'm working with Apple's sample code for [PhotoBrowse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums).

In the main view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method we have this code:

```
let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
```

This code sorts the photos by "creationDate". How do I determine/find the other valid values for these sort descriptors? For example, what if I wanted to sort photos by their file size, last modified date, etc.?

TIA!

Comment: Look at the table [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#1965657)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the available sort descriptors in the documentation for [PhotoKit PHFetchOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#1965657).

Note, there are NO descriptors that allow for sorting by photo/movie file size.